# Convertir a byte una imagen para guardarla en sql server desde c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo un formulario en asp.net y uso la herramienta FileUpload:

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

para cargar una imagen ahora lo que necesito es guardarla en una tabla de base de datos en un campo de tipo varbinary.

```
con.Open();
string query = "INSERT INTO TablaUser (Nombre, Edad, Correo, Imagen)
values (@Nombre, @Edad, @Correo, @Imagen)";
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", nomp.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", edad.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", mail.Text);
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
  //guardar imagen
}
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

```sql
Id int
Nombre varchar(MAX)
Edad varchar(2)
correo varchar(MAX)
Imagen varbinary(MAX)
```

Comment: ok pero que has intentado ? como es el codigo que usas para persistir en la db, tienes que poner la imagen como un campo varbinary o podrias poner la imagen en una carpeta y solo guardar la imagen en una carpeta del sitio web

Comment: El campo lo puse tipo imagen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para insertar la imagen tienes que poder obtener el `byte[]` de la imagen que se esta subiendo y pasarla por parametro

Algo como esto

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO TablaUser (Nombre, Edad, Correo, Imagen)
                    values (@Nombre, @Edad, @Correo, @Imagen)";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", nomp.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", edad.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Correo", mail.Text);

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    byte[] input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", input);
}
else
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imagen", DBNull.Value);
}

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Entiendo que sino se sube una imagen el campo permite `null`

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que guardas tu imagen como tipo binario:

```
public static void GuardaFotoUsuario(string imageFilePath)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress; 
Initial Catalog=MorganDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
        sqlconnection.Open();


        // Converts image file into byte[]
        byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFilePath);
               //tabla usuario campo photo es binario
        string insertXmlQuery = @"Insert Into [UserTable] (UserID,[Photo]) Values(1,@Photo)";


        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertXmlQuery, sqlconnection);
        SqlParameter sqlParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", imgData);
        sqlParam.DbType = DbType.Binary;
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

//Leer imagen
public static image LeerImagenDeUsuario(int userID)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress; 
Initial Catalog=MorganDB; Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
    {
        sqlconnection.Open();

        string selectQuery =string.Format(@"Select [Photo] From [UserTable] Where UserID={0}"
                            ,userID);

        // Lectura imagen de tabla
        image photo;
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlconnection);
        SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] imgData = (byte[])reader[0];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData))
            {
                System.Drawing.Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);

            }
        }
    return photo;
    }
}
```

saludos

Comment: y como puedo mostrar la imagen? despues de leerla, saludos

Comment: Hay diferentes formas, una de ellas es que tengas un folder publico y cada que lees la imagen la guardas en el folder y lo estableces como recurso para la imagen url="tuFolder/imagen1.jpg", otra es que tengas un handler para l[a [imagen](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Generic-Handler-to-display-Binary-Image-from-database-in-ASPNet.aspx), otra podria ser un que cargues la imagen y la agregues a la pagina como un recurso blob, conbinando con javascript